# Error while installing python package llama-cpp-python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, installation, pip

When I run the line "!pip install llama-cpp-python" in visual studio, I get the error:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Does someone know how to solve this?

I tried different python versions, but without succes.

Comment: That is not even close to what is the actual error .. But  I'll make an educated quess. This package is provided as source only, Have you installed visualstudio *compiler* ?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: I downloaded the C++ compiler for visual studio and now it is working, thanks!